# Can't load background script - manifest.json - Angular Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm a beginner programmer and I will gladly accept good advice from experienced colleagues.
I write my chrome plugin, but I encountered a problem with the background script attachment. When installing the plugin, there is a problem that informs in free translation that the "background.js' script operating in the background failed to load. You can't load the manifest file.

I tried to change background.js file content, its name, location. Add permissions, script types, I looked through all possible guides and solutions, but the script loading error still occurs, even with an empty background.js. Ofcourse manifest.json and background.js are in the same location.

Manifest.json file:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "firstExt",
  "description": "My first extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "minimum_chrome_version": "92",
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "://*/"
  ]
}
```

***Solution***
I found out, so I'm sharing the answer.
The whole problem was in the hashing mechanism placed in the agnular. When compiling TS to JS, angular appends a unique hash to the filenames.

```
main.091238ajksbdkjadad12.js
polyfills.asbd12387y8127yna.js
runtime.213987asjdknaasde.js
background.ansbdk71238213ya.js
styles.231jn23k1h4i123bhj1.css
```

Which makes the missing background.js message true because it didn't exist. There was background.ansbdk71238213ya.js

The hashing option can be disabled with just one line of code in manifest.json:

```
"outputHashing": "none"
```

Comment: Please indent your manifest.json.

Answer (score 0):

Try this very simple background script and I think it will clarify your problem.

[image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "service_worker",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
console.log("background.js");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I'm sure i posted here an update, but i dont see it :/ 
However, I found issue with my code. It was 'hashing' in names when Angular compiled ts to js. Alert was right: there wasn't background.js, there was fe. background-726dbashas.js.
Next step is to find a way to edit context menu in chrome. If you wanna help, let me know :)